# jQuery: Removing adding/removing a plugin based on window size

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a fully responsive layout..,

I've got the following code to add a function depending on browser size, but how do I remove the effects of this plugin if the browser is resized? (Currently it only works if the page is loaded at the specific size, not if it's resized)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() >= 420) {
          // Enable the plugin to make the tab functionality...
          $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
      }
      else {
        // Code needed to completely disable the tab functionality??
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to grab the class using a media query then display: none;.

Comment: Because I still need the contents of the tabs to display, disabling the function is definitely what I need i'm afraid.  I'll probably use media queries to disable the tab navigation, but that's about it.